# Build Docker Image from Executable (.exe file)

Tags: docker

I would like to build a Docker image from an .exe file. In my folder I have an executable `main.exe` which prints “Hello World“ in the console and a `Dockerfile` like this:

```
FROM scratch
COPY . /usr/scr
ENTRYPOINT [ “usr/src/main.exe“ ]
```

There is no error with `docker build -t app:1 .`, however, when executing `docker run -it app:1` there is neither an error nor an output.

I already read something about file permission when copying and using the `--chmod=0777` flag, that did not solved my problem, though.

Comment: Could be this path? COPY . /usr/scr ENTRYPOINT [ “usr/sry/main.exe“ ]. You are copying the file to /usr/scr an running /usr/sry. Are you trying to run a exe with a linux container?

Comment: @btafarelo sry typo. I‘d like to run an .exe file, I do not know which would be the best base image.

Comment: Where does the `main.exe` file come from?  Is it a Windows or Linux binary?  Is it statically linked?

Comment: @DavidMaze I compiled a C++ program on Visual Studio (Windows) and that is the output .exe, from which I would like to build a Docker image (without compiling in building process).